# Visual Studio 2010: Scrolling in Text Editor makes the Solution Explorer scroll instead

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a fresh install of Visual Studio 2010 installed with SP1 on my machine.

I've noticed that when I have some code or layout file open in my text editor, if I attempt to scroll using the mouse wheel, the Solution Explorer will scroll up and down instead of my file.

I found that this only happens when the Solution Explorer is docked and when the project directories are expanded enough that the Solution Explorer has scroll bars. When it's not docked (i.e Auto-Hide) or when all projects are closed so that there aren't scroll bars, my text editor will scroll correctly.

I've made sure I've clicked in the text editor, and it should have context.

Any ideas?

I've had this issue a couple of years ago, and fixed it back then, but can't remember how to do it. I'm thinking it was a Visual Studio HotFix, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: I found some links with the same issue... none of which are resolved.
http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/fantastically-annoying-scroll-feature-105596.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is an issue with my Lenovo Mouse, and the Lenovo Mouse Suite installed on my computer.
You can fix this issue by removing the Mouse Suite program from your computer, and making the mouse use the MS Windows drivers instead.

http://thecurlybrace.blogspot.com.au/2010/08/mouse-scroll-whell-issues-with-visual.html